# javascript delete a selected element in a select list

Tags: javascript

The HTML of the select list is:

```
<div class="textf_rechts">
<select style="height: 14em; width: 300px" size="10" name="hersteller">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select> </div>
```

I want to delete the sected element so I tried:

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select').selectedIndex;
select.removeChild(select[select.selectedIndex]);
```

but it returns that select variable is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select').selectedIndex;
select.removeChild(select[select.selectedIndex]);
```

...you're setting `select` to be `undefined`, because you're trying to access the `selectedIndex` property on a `NodeList`. `NodeLists` don't have a `selectedIndex` property. Then you try to call `removeChild` on `undefined`.

It should be more like this:

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
if (select && select.selectedIndex >= 0) {
    select.removeChild(select[select.selectedIndex]);
}
```

We get the first select box, then **if** there is one and it has something selected, we remove that selected item.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/icUWuFEc/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/icUWuFEc/1/edit)

Comment: it returns select.selectedIndex is undefined

Comment: @user1987: It shouldn't, see the live example I just added.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I've always been a stackoverflow reader than a poster, Sorry! Only getting used to stuff here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <div class="textf_rechts">
        <select id ="select" style="height: 14em; width: 300px" size="10" name="hersteller">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select> 
    </div>
```

Js

```
var element = document.getElementById("select");
element.options[element.selectedIndex].remove();
```